# Hover function does not work in CSS Side Bar

Tags: html, css

I have written code for an HTML/CSS website sidebar, and I want to make sure that when a user hovers over an element in the sidebar, its background gets highlighted.

It just displays my normal list and the hover function does not work. What is the problem?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  background-color: #F4ECFC;
  /* Sidebar Background */
  width: 200px;
  /* Width of side bar */
  height: 900px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  /* Padding above the header */
  font-family: helvetica;
  /* Font for the sidebar */
}

.sidebar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Removes the underline from links. */
  color: #0B0036;
  /* Text color of the menu items */
}

.sidebar ul {
  line-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.sidebar ul li .listItemA {
  /* list-style-type: none; */
  background-color: #F4ECFC;
  /* Background colour of the menu items. */
}

.sidebar ul li .listItemA a:hover {
  background-color: purple;
}

.listItemA {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li class="listItemA"><a href="#">Class1</a></li>

    <li class="listItemA"><a href="#">Class2</a></li>

    <li class="listItemA"><a href="#">Class3</a></li>

    <li class="listItemA"><a href="#">Class4</a></li>

    <li class="listItemA"><a href="#">Class5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the space from `li .listItemA`

Comment: I did, now it just highlights a little box around the texts in the list but not a large rectangle

Comment: That's because you attached :hover to the `<a>` and that's all the space that the `<a>` occupies. If you want it to highlight the block that the `<li>` occupies then do `li.listItemA:hover` instead

Answer (score 0):

One thing you want to do first is give your links `display: block;` which makes them take up 100% of the width available.

Then simplify the style of the link and the relative hover like so:

```
.sidebar ul .listItemA {
  /* list-style-type: none; */
  background-color: #F4ECFC;
  /* Background colour of the menu items. */
}

.sidebar ul .listItemA:hover a {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

As pointed out in a comment on your question you had a space between `li` and `.listItemA`, I just removed `li` to achieve the correct selector but you could've also changed that part of the selector to `li.listItemA`.

Really important change here is to style the link on hover of the list item:

```
.sidebar ul .listItemA:hover a { ... }
```

This tells the browser to change the background of the link when the list item is hovered.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  background-color: #F4ECFC;
  /* Sidebar Background */
  width: 200px;
  /* Width of side bar */
  height: 900px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  /* Padding above the header */
  font-family: helvetica;
  /* Font for the sidebar */
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Removes the underline from links. */
  color: #0B0036;
  /* Text color of the menu items */
}

.sidebar ul {
  line-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.sidebar ul .listItemA {
  /* list-style-type: none; */
  background-color: #F4ECFC;
  /* Background colour of the menu items. */
}

.sidebar ul .listItemA:hover a {
  background-color: purple;
}

.listItemA {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li class="listItemA"><a href="#">Class1</a></li>

    <li class="listItemA"><a href="#">Class2</a></li>

    <li class="listItemA"><a href="#">Class3</a></li>

    <li class="listItemA"><a href="#">Class4</a></li>

    <li class="listItemA"><a href="#">Class5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```